# How to Integrate Dialogflow ES with Twilio SMS

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es

Has anyone worked on how to integrate Twilio with Dialogflow so people can text a number in their phones and get answers from Dialogflow?
I have looked everywhere and no luck.
The documentation I found on the Dialogflow integrations session was not very helpful:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/twilio#readme

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you managed to send and receive messages with Twilio? And can you use the Dialogflow API to send queries and receive responses? Once you have those two parts you should be able to connect the two. If you have tried any of this and got errors or specific questions, please let me know what has happened and I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it and integrated my nodejs app that is a custom for Dialogflow with Twilio.
The documentation is a little confusing but these are the steps:

- Requirements:

- Twilio account
- Dialogflow Agent
- Create a Service account in GCP with role: Dialogflow Client API, create a key and save json file (If deploying using Cloud Run).
- Enable Cloud Build and Cloud Run API
- Setup Gcloud command line tool

- Getting Started:

- Clone and open the repository for Dialogflow Open Source Integrations: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations.git
- Open Twilio’s folder inside dialogflow-integrations with an editor and open the Dockerfile. Change the ENV INTEGRATION=YOUR_INTEGRATION to ENV INTEGRATION=twilio, then open server.js and. update projectId with Dialogflow’s project ID, accountSid, AuthToken, phoneNumber with Twilio’s Account SID and Auth Token and Phone Number.
- Purchase a number with Twilio
- Run these commands inside dialogflow-integrations folder:

  - gcloud init
  - gcloud config set project dialogflow-proj-name
  - gcloud config get-value project (to make sure the variable is set)
  - gcloud builds submit --tag http://gcr.io/dialogflow-proj-name/dialogflow-twilio
  - gcloud beta run deploy --image http://gcr.io/dialogflow-proj-name/dialogflow-twilio --update-env-vars GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key_that_you_downloaded_previously.json --memory 1Gi
- Copy the URL provided

Go to Twilio’s portal and in the "Phone Number" section, go to Active Numbers and click on the purchased number. In "Messaging", paste URL by "A message comes in" and HTTP POST box field. Set the drop-down to Webhook and the HTTP method to HTTP POST.